# SQL when join table twice the result will display only when both tables are populated

Tags: sql

SQL when join table twice the result will display only when both tables are populated.

```
SELECT D.Date, T1.SUM, T2.SUM FROM DATE AS D
LEFT JOIN T1 AS T1
ON T1.DATE = D.Date
LEFT JOIN T2 AS T2
ON T2.DATE = D.Date
```

If I have Date Table and then I LEFT JOIN two tables (each of them contains Date/Time and SUM)

I would like to display all the result like this:

[image: 2020-01-01]

BUT the output is:

[image]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Can you please share a query?

Comment: I'm not looking for a code solution, all that I need is theory explanation - How to join two tables that end table will display all values from both tables

Comment: Have added sample query

Comment: Does T1 contain the values 1,2,3 for those dates? If it does then they should be in the results.

Comment: What do tables 1 and 2 look like? Are there only entries for dates on which there is a non-null sum? I'm not able to reproduce the problem on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d4798a/1 (partial data) ... though my interpretation of the underlying tables may be wrong.

Comment: `WHERE T1.SUM IS NULL + T2.SUM IS NULL != 1` (in MySQL syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tbh I cant reproduce your result on mysql. These are my tables, my query and my result. Is this your real query? It seems like you do a left join for T2 with T2.Date=T1.Date?

Table Test1

```
+------+------+
| A    | B    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    5 |
|    2 |    3 |
|    3 |    4 |
+------+------+
```

Table Test2

```
+------+------+
| A    | B    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    5 |
|    3 |    3 |
+------+------+
```

Table Test3

```
+------+------+
| A    | B    |
+------+------+
|    2 |    5 |
|    3 |    6 |
+------+------+

select 
  t1.A,
  t2.B as B1,
  t3.B as B2 
from Test1 t1 
  left join Test2 t2 on  t2.A=t1.A 
  left join Test3 t3 on t3.A=t1.A

+------+------+------+
| A    | B1   | B2   |
+------+------+------+
|    2 | NULL |    5 |
|    3 |    3 |    6 |
|    1 |    5 | NULL |
+------+------+------+
```